# Efficient Euclidean distance for coordinates in different size lists in python

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I've got two large point lists. One holds points that represent the edges of a rectangle (edge_points). Edge_points has xy coordinates. The other list holds points within the rectangle (all_point). All_point has xyz coordinates. In the second list, I want to remove any points that are within xy "m" distance of the points around the edge (list 1).

I have a functioning code but it is very slow what with the nested loops ... I've seen threads that suggest cdist but that won't work for my scenario where I want to compare each point in the rectangle to a single edge point. Hypot is faster than using sqrt, but still doesn't get me where I want to be.

How do I increase the efficiency of this code?

```
all_point=colpoint+rowpoint
all_points=[]
for n in range(0,len(all_point)):
    #Calculate xy distance between inflection point and edge points
    test_point=all_point[n]
    dist=[]
    for k in range(0,len(edge_points)):
        test_edge=edge_points[k]
        dist_edge=math.hypot((test_point[1]-test_edge[1])+(test_point[0]-test_edge[0]))
        dist.append(dist_edge)
    if all(i >= m for i in dist) is True:
        all_points.append(test_point)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood but why can't you use cdist? You can give a list of each point in rectangle as first argument, and a single point as second argument to sklearn cdist.

Comment: You probably should use numpy for that and vectorise your loops. That alone should give you a massive speedup.

Comment: Yeah, you probably arent going to outperform `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances`

Comment: @umutto I forgot to mention that list1 is in 2D and list2 is in 3D .... I'm not sure how to reconcile these points for cdist without more loops. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Vectorise, vectorise* also applies here:

```
import numpy as np

all_point, edge_points = np.asanyarray(all_point), np.asanyarray(edge_points)
squared_dists = ((all_point[:, None, :2] - edge_points[None, :, :])**2).sum(axis=-1)
mask = np.all(squared_dists > m**2, axis=-1)
all_points = all_point[mask, :]
```

Observe that at the Python level there are no more loops. Vectorisation moves these loops to compiled code which executes several-fold faster.

Specifically, we have created two arrays `all_point` of size `N1x2` and `edge_points` of size `N2x2`. These were then reshaped to sizes `N1x1x2` and `1xN2x2` (by the `None`s in the indexing).

When taking the difference this triggers broadcasting of the first two axes, such that the resulting array has shape `N1xN2x2` and contains all the pairwise differences between coordinates of `all_point` and `edge_points`. The subsequent squaring applies to all `N1xN2x2` elements in one go. The sum, as specified by the `axis` parameter is taken along the last axis, i.e. over `x` and `y` to yield an `N1xN2` array of squared pairwise distances.

The next lines demonstrate the vectorised equivalent of `if` statements. To be able to perform them in one go one creates truth masks. The comparison with `m**2` is done elementwise, therefore we get a truth value for each of the `N1xN2` elements of `squared_dists`. `np.all` is similar to Python `all` but can do multiple groups simultaneously. This is controlled by the `axis` parameter. Here it specifies that `all` should be applied row-wise yielding `N1` truth values.

This mask matches `all_point` in shape and can be used to extract all the coordinate pairs that fulfil the criterion.

To summarise broadcasting permitted to eliminate a nested loop from the Python level and replace it with a few vectorised operations. As long as memory is not an issue this comes with a massive speedup.

If memory is an issue: Here is a memory-saving variant that uses `tensordot`

```
all_point, edge_points = np.asanyarray(all_point), np.asanyarray(edge_points)
mixed = np.tensordot(all_point[:, :2], -2 * edge_points, (1, 1))
mixed += (all_point[:, :2]**2).sum(axis=-1)[:, None]
mixed += (edge_points**2).sum(axis=-1)[None, :]
mask = np.all(mixed > m**2, axis=-1)
all_points = all_point[mask, :]
```

If that's still too big, we'll have to chop up `all_point` or `edge_points` into manageable bits.

```
all_point, edge_points = np.asanyarray(all_point), np.asanyarray(edge_points)
mask = np.ones((len(all_point),), dtype=bool)
mm = m*m - (all_point[:,:2]**2).sum(axis=-1)[:, None]
chunksize = <choose according to your memory and data size>
for i in range(0, len(edge_points), chunksize):
    mixed = np.tensordot(all_point[mask, :2], -2 * edge_points[i:i+chunksize, :], (1, 1))
    mixed += (edge_points[None, i:i+chunksize, :]**2).sum(axis=-1)
    mask[mask] &= np.all(mixed > mm[mask], axis=-1)
all_points = all_point[mask, :]
```

Comment: So running this with my current lists, one with xy and one with xyz points, throws an error since the dimensions aren't the same .... added some placeholder z values for my edge_points (need the z values for all_point) and it threw a memory error. Not sure what to do about that..

Comment: @JCH How large are your lists? Instead of padding placeholders you could slice away the _z_. I'll add it to the code and also some other memory saving strategies.

Comment: @JCH I've added to variants that save memory. The second has a parameter `chunksize` which you can adjust to control memory consumption.

Comment: edge_points is about 1700 points and all_point is about 18000. This will be pretty typical for the swaths (rectangles) I need to run. I'll give your new suggestions a try

Comment: that second code worked really well! Total runtime now is around 20s when before it was over a minute. I'm going to spend some time trying to understand vectorizing loops .... I've got a few other nested loops that could be sped up using this logic. Thanks!